# in my silverlight application some lines display more dark, and some display light even though they all having same stroke

Tags: silverlight

I am using line array in that all lines having same stroke.
but at the time of display there is difference in there stroke. 
some are more dark and some are more light.
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the effect of subpixel (floating point) positioning of UI elements in Silverlight. It should not happen if you leave UseLayoutRounding set to false (default).